# "N, total number of documents with field" from explain API is much greater than my actual # of documents

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I was trying to use the `explain:true` clause to understand the scoring of my results and I found out the `idf` has something like this:

```
                                           {
                                           "value": 6.660968,
                                           "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                                           "details": [
                                               {
                                                   "value": 37,
                                                   "description": "n, number of documents containing term",
                                                   "details": []
                                               },
                                               {
                                                   "value": 29298,
                                                   "description": "N, total number of documents with field",
                                                   "details": []
                                               }
                                           ]
                                       },
```

The problem is I definitely do not have `29298` these many documents. To confirm, I count the documents as below and there are only 983 documents. Does anyone know what's going on here? Thanks!

```
curl 'https://xxxxxx/_cat/count?v=true'

epoch      timestamp count
1677353551 19:32:31  983
```

I tried to search wiki on `idf` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) as well and it seems like N is just **total number of documents**

Also, the deleted docs are miminal:

```
curl 'https://xxx/_cat/indices?v=true'
health status index     uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   en-us     kYD_PY9mRNm9wWsVYtNl8w   3   2         12            5    520.3kb        173.4kb
green  open   ds-en-us  OmhX5FMgRTqOCXQEZUP0fA   3   2        141           32        4mb          1.3mb
green  open   .kibana_1 bxMRa2KEQc2Scl3r9dUsfQ   1   1          1            0       10kb            5kb
green  open   en-gb     Ao6rToHPRmmx9LJx3HI0LQ   3   2         73           13      1.3mb        336.6kb
green  open   ds-en-gb  SOhhP4-kQ9iK8niSI_paOg   3   1        753           34    817.5mb         13.5mb
```

Answer (score 2):

have you deleted documents from that index? If yes, that could be the reason. In fact, the total number of documents also includes documents still in the index but marked as deleted ([source from elastic](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/understanding-doc-and-doccount-values-in-explain-response/158383/2))

###### Update:

As a follow-up, are you often updating documents? Because when you update a document, under the hood in Lucene, you're marking the old document as deleted and creating a new one. So, for example, if you update the same document 100 times, you'll have one document returned from your search, but 101 documents in your segments.

If this could be your case, you may try to execute a `_forcemerge` on your index ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-forcemerge.html)), which - among other things - frees up the space used by deleted documents. But do keep in mind that it's a best practice to force merge only read-only indices

Comment: Thx. My docs deleted are minimal. I added the snippet above.

Comment: thanks! that made me think of another possibility, i.e., updating a document. Let me add that to my answer

Comment: Sounds very promising! Yes this is a testing cluster used by a lot of folks. Let me read on and try then report back. Thanks!